# Should inline routes be checked before or after global routes?

Tags: c#, web-frameworks, api-design

I'm writing a web framework, and one neat feature (IMO) is that you can define the web address for a function inline, like so:

```
[Url(@"/profile:(?<username>\w+)")]
public void Profile(string username)
```

And then that function will automatically get called when you visit `/profile:someusername` and `someusername` will get passed into the function and get type-casted automatically.

But for those that like the old way of doing things, you can still specify all the routes in one place:

```
List<Route> Routes = new List<Route> {
    new Route(@"/user:(?<id>\d+)", "UserController.View")
};
```

Now I'm just trying to decide what order the two different methods should be handled in.

OOH, putting the global routes first means you could handle all the special cases upfront before the inline routes snatch em up, but OTOH, if you put the global ones up front you can't put all the fall-back routes there. So I can't quite decide which order is better...

The other solution I guess is to use a priority queue and users can give higher or lower precedence to certain routes.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, more specific routes should be predecent to general routes, simply because they specify a more specific behaviour.

I like this feature btw, as it removes the specific routes from the global definition and doesn't clutter it, so you have a much better overview, and you don't specify them in methods but actually where they are used, which helps readability.

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, I think I agree with you on this. If I do it this way, and then add a simple (optional) 3-level priority for special cases, I think my bases are covered.